# fillMaxSize priority inside Column unclear

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What I need to do is a box with a fixed size, and another one under the first one, that will fill left space. I have following code:

```
Column {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .fillMaxSize()
    )
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .height(50.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            "hello",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

For some reason the bottom box is half size under the column bounds, and if I remove strict `.height(50.dp)`, it'll disappear at all. I tried to
solve this second problem with `.wrapContentHeight()`, but no luck - looks like `fillMaxSize()` of the top box making it size equal to the `Column` and that's why it's pushing part of the bottom one down. I expect it to fill size left after other Column children size gets calculated - am I missing something?
If I change the order of the boxes, it works as expected, but I need the bottom one to be fixed size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such cases [`weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#weight) modifier should be used on the view instead of `fillMaxSize` (`weight` already will fill max size by default), in this case it'll be measured after other views:

> The parent will divide the vertical space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

```
Column {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .weight(1f)
    )
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            "hello",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```