# Jetpack Compose Row Drawing Order Problem

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with Jetpack Compose Row.

[image]

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun TopBar() {
    val height = 50.dp

    @Composable
    fun LeftLongBar() {
        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                .padding(end = 10.dp),
            elevation = 5.dp
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "37 / 142",
                    color = CustomColors.dark,
                    fontSize = 25.sp
                )
                Text(
                    text = "B2",
                    color = CustomColors.dark,
                    fontSize = 25.sp
                )
            }

        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun RightSettingsBar() {
        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(height),
            elevation = 5.dp
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Outlined.Settings,
                contentDescription = "Settings",
                modifier = Modifier.size(height),
                tint = CustomColors.dark
            )
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(height)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = height)
    ) {
        LeftLongBar()
        RightSettingsBar()
    }
}
```

The first image is my code's result. The second image is rendered result with changed bar's order. Second image is just called RightSettingsBar() first, LeftLongBar() second.

In my default code, i can't see the setting button on the right. I think that's because of the Modifier.fillMaxWidth() in the LeftLongBar() card. LeftLongBar() renders first and takes all the width of row. But i want to fill its width of remaining space. How can i fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Box.fillMaxSize priority inside Column unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756794/box-fillmaxsize-priority-inside-column-unclear)

Comment: You need to create a parameter of `LeftLongBar` and pass `Modifier.weight(1f)` there

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two items in a constraintlayout. Make sure to set your card to use fillMaxSize:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TopBar() {
    val height = 50.dp

    @Composable
    fun LeftLongBar() {
        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(end = 10.dp),
            elevation = 5.dp
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "37 / 142",
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    fontSize = 25.sp
                )
                Text(
                    text = "B2",
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    fontSize = 25.sp
                )
            }
        }

    }

    @Composable
    fun RightSettingsBar() {
        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(height),
            elevation = 5.dp
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Outlined.Settings,
                contentDescription = "Settings",
                modifier = Modifier.size(height),
                tint = Color.Blue
            )
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(height)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = height)
    ) {

        ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            val (left, right) = createRefs()

            Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(right) {
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }) {
                RightSettingsBar()
            }

            Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(left) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(right.start)
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            }) {
                LeftLongBar()
            }
        }
    }
}
```